# Cgo + windows + mingw-w64 : "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in"

Tags: go, mingw, mingw-w64, cgo

While trying to install [suapapa/go_sass](https://github.com/suapapa/go_sass) on windows 8.1 with the command :

```
go get github.com/suapapa/go_sass
```

I came across this error :

> cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

According to stackoverflow and other forums, this problem comes from the fact that i don't have the right mingw version (correct me if i'm wrong). My go version is 1.3.3 windows/amd64.

So i tried installing a 64 bit version of gcc that i found on http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/.

I still can't seem to go get the package i want to install. Any help ? I'm not familiar with c compilers at all.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using such an old version of Go?

Comment: Nope, updating now !

Comment: Update : Go 1.5 doesn't seem to change anything for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the installation process of mingw-64,you should select Architecture "i686" as I did.
If so, the architecture "x86_64" should work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/articles/2021-05/10.3.0-release)..! It worked for me.

Also remember to add `C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin` to `Path` in the environment variables.